# Passing print function within another function

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop, random

I decided I would create a simple text-based game as a learning project for Python as this is my first time using it. I have this function *slow_print* that simulates human typing which works in it's current form for strings, however is it possible to pass through a function instead. As I would like to break up the game text into sections for tidiness.

```
def slow_print(t):
    for letter in t:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/55)
    print ('')
```

```
def intro():
    print("Welcome, this is a text-based adventure game.")
    print("This isn't designed for the light hearted so proceed at your own peril.")
    ...
    ...
```

Is this possible in Python? After playing around with the params and passing it through I got the error of "Python object is not iterableable". From my understanding strings would be iterateable. Would there be another easier way to accomplish this?

```
slow_print(intro())
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CDN Admin\Python\game.py", line 20, in <module>
    slow_print(intro())
  File "C:\Users\CDN Admin\Python\game.py", line 9, in slow_print
    for letter in t:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: _After playing around with the params and passing it through I got the error of "Python object is not iterableable"_ Show us the actual code you tried, and the full error traceback message.

Comment: The argument str that you use is actually the string class in python. Rename your variable. Str is not iterable because it is a built-in function

Comment: @Fredericka Yeah that was one of my initial attempts but it doesn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should rename the variable `str` inside the function `slow_print`.

`str` is a reserved keyword in python and it should be the cause of your error.

I have tried this solution without issues:

```py
import sys
import time
import random

def slow_print(t):
    for letter in t:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random() * 10.0 / 55)
    print('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    slow_print("Welcome, this is a text-based adventure game.")
```

Comment: I attempted this earlier but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. I updated my question to reflect.

Comment: I've updated my initial answer to reflect what I've tested. Please see that it works.

Comment: Appreciate the help - but that is nothing close to what my question request is. @yogaxpto

Answer (score 0):

`slow_print` takes text and slowly prints it. For it to work, you have to give it text.

`intro` does not return text. It prints text directly, then automatically returns `None`, the default return value for functions that don't explicitly return something else. `slow_print` then receives `None` and tries to slowly print it, but `None` is not text.

You need to restructure your code so the text that needs to be slowly printed is passed to `slow_print` instead of `print`. That might involve giving `intro` a parameter to select how to print things:

```
def intro(printer=print):
    printer("Welcome, this is a text-based adventure game.")
    printer("This isn't designed for the light hearted so proceed at your own peril.")
    ...
    ...

intro(slow_print)
```

In this modified code, `intro` has a `printer` parameter that it will use to print things. This parameter defaults to the built-in `print` function, but if you pass `slow_print` instead, `intro` will use `slow_print` to print its messages.

Answer (score 0):

`slow_print(intro())` prints what `intro()` returns, and this function does not return anything.  You can rewrite this function.

```
def intro():
    rerurn '''Welcome, this is a text-based adventure game.
    This isn't designed for the light hearted so proceed at your own peril.'''
```

Then your `slow_print` will print intro message.

P. S. If you use `intro()` elsewhere, you should replace `intro()`to `print(intro())`.